# Any good tools for automating mySQL Queries verification?

Tags: mysql, testing, automated-tests, bigdata

I can't find a proper answer to this so here it goes. I work on a (sort of) big data project where we get tons of info from different sources in different shapes and forms. We then transform that into a normalized form, split that result in multiple tables, etc.

Everytime we modify or implement a new source, it goes like this. 1. I download the info. 2. I process the info. 3. I spend the whole day running queries checking data manually.

Any ideas or how do you recommend I Automate this part of my verification? (A specific tool, mySQL procedures maybe? just use workbench?) The only thing I'm trying to avoid is adding another layer, like an API or something, I should be able to do this hitting the DB directly

Comment: This question is too generic for Stack Overflow. If you ask a question about a specific verification problem we can help. In general, data verification should either be done in the database or in a data model, not by hand. if you're using MySQL >= 8.0.16, and I hope you are, [`check` constraints](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/) now work.

Answer (score 0):

Data validation should happen inside the database, or as close to it as possible, to ensure the data is valid and remains valid.

---

Step zero: MySQL is very lax. Many times it will accept or truncate data that other databases would reject. Put it in a more strict mode, at least [`traditional` mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important).

---

First, use the correct column types. Probably the most important is to use the [date and time types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) for dates and times, not strings nor numbers. These types will provide their own validations, ensure they are properly formatted, and offer [a host of useful functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

---

Then add [constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp) on what data is allowed in a column. The most basic of these are [`not null` constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp) to ensure data is filled in with something, [`unique` constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) to ensure there's only one of a thing, and [`default`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) to ensure a default value is filled in.

For more general checks use [check constraints](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/), which MySQL finally supports as of 8.0.16. And finally [triggers](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-triggers/) offer the most powerful constraints.

For example, let's say you have a table full of user data. Your business logic requires that...

- The user must have a login name.
- The login name must be unique.
- The user has credits which starts at 0 and cannot be less than 0.

```
create table users (
  id bigint primary key auto_increment,
  login varchar(255) not null unique check(length(login) > 0),
  credits integer not null default 0 check(credits >= 0)
);
```

It is now impossible to have two users with the same login, or a user with no login, or a blank login, or a negative credit balance.

```
mysql> insert into users (login) values ('');
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'users_chk_1' is violated.
```

---

When it comes to relationships, use [foreign key constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) to ensure relationships aren't broken. Use [referential actions](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) to clean up related data.

Let's say you have a second table to track user logins.

```
create table user_logins (
  user_id bigint not null,
  login_at datetime not null default current_timestamp,
  foreign key(user_id) references users(id) on delete cascade
)
```

It's now impossible to have a user_logins entry without the associated user. Nor can it not have a timestamp, nor a formatted timestamp. And the default means you don't need to supply a timestamp avoiding another possible data error. Just give it a valid user ID.

```
insert into user_logins (user_id) values (5)
```

`on delete cascade` ensures that when a user is deleted, their associated user_logins are also deleted.

```
-- All of user 5's user_logins are also deleted.
delete from users where id = 5
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e23e8d4e02f3248d011e55fb3effb726)

---

Finally, use [transactions](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx) when changing data. A transaction only saves its changes when they're all complete.

For example, let's say we want to move 100 credits from user 5 to user 10.

```
begin
  -- I've deliberately added credits first to demonstrate transactions.
  update users
  set credits = credits + 100
  where id = 10;

  update users
  set credits = credits - 100
  where id = 5;
end
```

If user 5 doesn't have 100 credits the second update fails (because of our check constraint), the transaction rolls back, and nothing is changed. Without transactions, user 10 gets a free 100 credits.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load new data into a staging table.
2. Build a Stored Procedure to run lots of validation queries against that table.
3. Hone your SQL skills so you can keep adding to the SP.